# Disable scroll through DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and scroll through datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with two columns (`DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and `DataGRidViewComboBoxColumn`).  If I click on a cell in the textbox column and scroll with the mousewheel, the grid scrolls.  This is perfect.

If I click on a cell in the combobox column, the mousewheel will scroll the items in the combobox.  I need to scroll the datagridview instead.

In my attempt to fix I can disable the scrolling in the combobox by handling the `EditingControlShowing` event :

```
private void SeismicDateGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Control is IDataGridViewEditingControl)
     {
          dgvCombo = (IDataGridViewEditingControl) e.Control;

          ((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)dgvCombo).MouseWheel -= new MouseEventHandler(DGVCombo_MouseWheel);
          ((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)dgvCombo).MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(DGVCombo_MouseWheel);
     }
}

private void DGVCombo_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
     HandledMouseEventArgs mwe = (HandledMouseEventArgs)e;
     mwe.Handled = true;
}
```

Any ideas how to scroll the DataGridView when the `DataGridViewComboBox` column is active ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered handling the ComboBox's DropDownClosed event and changing the focus to the parent?

```
void DateGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox = dataGridView.EditingControl as System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox;
    if (comboBox != null)
    {
        comboBox.DropDownClosed += comboBox_DropDownClosed;
    }
}

void comboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox).DropDownClosed -= comboBox_DropDownClosed;
    (sender as System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox).Parent.Focus();
}
```

If you want to scroll the DataGridView before you select a cell but while the ComboBox is still dropped down, that would be a different situation but judging by what you said here:

> If I click on a cell in the combobox column, the mousewheel will
>   scroll the items in the combobox.

I am assuming that you simply want to change the focus once a selection has been made.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the input using P/Invoke like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280310/Redirect-Mouse-Wheel-Events-To-Unfocused-Windows-F). Or you could subclass the `DataGridView` to add a `Scroll` Method to it which calls the base class's `OnMouseWheel` method, which you could then call from `DGVCombo_MouseWheel`. Example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/143450/How-to-scroll-a-parent-control-with-mouse-wheel-wh).

I think the second option is probably the most elegant, no reason to use PInvoke.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is done with inline functions. And handled case, when combo box is dropped down:

```
dgv.EditingControlShowing += (s, e) =>
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl editingControl = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (editingControl != null)
            editingControl.MouseWheel += (s2, e2) =>
                {
                    if (!editingControl.DroppedDown)
                    {
                        ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e2).Handled = true;
                        dgv.Focus();
                    }
                };
    };
```